# Math formula with MYSQL trigger outputs incorrect calculation

Tags: mysql, triggers

I couldn't find anything on the site specifically addressing this issue,so I decided to post a question for some help.

I'm trying to run a "*BEFORE UPDATE*" trigger on a table in my database. The trigger is set to execute after a cron job query runs to evaluate user data.  If the data targets are met ,then *BEFORE UPDATE* trigger kicks in to manipulate additional columns via two simple math formulas.

sqlQuery (via cron job)

UPDATE `table1`.`records` SET `date_created`=IF(`expiration_date`<(CURDATE()),IF(`postCOUNT`>0,CURDATE(),'error'),`date_created`)

BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGER (created via phpMyAdmin cPanel)

```
1. BEGIN
2.    IF NEW.date_created != OLD.date_created THEN
3.         SET NEW.date_created=New.date_created;
4.         SET NEW.expiration_date = NEW.date_created + 2;
5.         SET NEW.postCOUNT = OLD.postCOUNT-1;
6.     END IF;
7. END
```

Now I'm sure there are far better ways of coding to accomplish this task but everything seems to working until the math formula in LINE 5 of the trigger.  Instead of subtracting "1" from OLD.postCOUNT, the formula keeps subtracting "2".  I'm baffled as to why this is happening,the formula seems straight-forward. I've even tried other numbers in the formula and still the answers are never correct.

Any advice or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try printing the NEW.postCOUNT and OLD.postCOUNT immediately before and after line 5?  What was the output?

Comment: Just want to clarify what are you doing in step 3?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion TravisJ....I moved line 5 above line 4....but still calculation are not right.  In fact, instead of subtracting "2", it subtracted "3" this time.

Comment: step 3...i was trying to say that that value was true.  actually im not sure if that line is needed at all